# Start workflow when an item is created on another site

Tags: sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow

Ok Say i have 2 subsites on sharepoint; Site1 and Site2.
Site1 has a list called "jobs".
when an item is created on the jobs list i want to automatically create a folder on the other site "Site 2 ". I was wondering is it possible to do this using a workflow. ?

Comment: You can't do anything cross site in Designer, it would have to be Visual Studio, and then, what you are asking is a little tricky but I don't think impossible, as long as you push the change to the other site, maybe a hidden list, with an event receiver to start the workflow. Reading from another site collection is easy, but starting a workflow can only give you theory and where to look. Is Visual Studio a possibility for you?

Comment: I could save the jobs list as a web part file and then add it as a web part to site 2 . Do you know if it is possible to add a workflow to this web part to run automatically when an item is added ?

Comment: A worflow won't fire automatically from a programmatic ItemAdded, but an event receiver will. Similar to this http://zimmergren.net/technical/starting-a-sharepoint-workflow-from-code-event-receiver it's the only thoughts in my head at the moment.